How do I use Filter function across multiple tabs?
I am working on a Key Dates sheet in Google and trying to set up different tabs with different department key dates, then use the Filter function to pull data from all tabs into the main tab, based on a condition (is a box checked).
I am using "=FILTER(AwardsDates,Awards_Key_Dates[Insert in Key Dates?]=TRUE)" which works for one tab, but I can't work out how to adjust this to cover all other tabs. Spreadsheet is here: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1gVocWTavcNS9XGHjSpt7Zrzi19YCPI0jxq2Xr07tp9o/edit#gid=1321993176

Use VSTACK() to stack all data to a array and then apply QUERY() function to keep TRUE marked rows. Try-
=QUERY(VSTACK(Awards!A2:G,Development!A2:G,Festival!A2:G,Events!A2:G,Misc!A2:G),"where Col6=TRUE")

If your sheets increase in future, then I would suggest to put all sheet names to a cell ranges and use REDUCE() function to iterate all those sheets and stack values using above formula. In this case when you will add a new sheet, then you just need to put that sheet name in that cells range and REDUCE() formula will grab that sheet data automatically.


Thanks ! Is there a way for this formula to then allow me to order and filter data? ie. This works perfectly, but when I go to organise the data column in my master sheet, it keeps data in the B column categories so won't mix rows based on date.

Yes, QUERY() function has order by clause. See this article https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093343?hl=en
